# DISTINCT Query for One Column but not any other columns

Tags: sql-server, distinct

I have a small 2 column table. Lets say the columns are A and B. Column A needs to be distinct so that it does not display a repeated value. Column B needs to have everything selected in the query so if there are multiple B values for a value in A, the multiple values will display. How can I write a query that will do this for me?

While the duplicates are now gone...there is a bunch of blank space in my dropdown.

[image]

Comment: Sample data and expected result will explain the problem better

Comment: I added a picture of sample data and what i would want it to look like

Comment: Better to do this in application layer. Also there are 4 rows for `2` out of 4 rows in which row you want to display `2`?

Answer (score 3):

You could use a CTE to simplify it:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
   SELECT A, B,
          RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A ORDER BY A, B)
   FROM dbo.TableName
)
SELECT A = CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN Cast(A as varchar(50)) ELSE '' END,
       B
FROM CTE
```

Comment: how would this look if im assigning it to a variable in php?

Comment: @Rataiczak24: i don't understand the question. It's just a sql query.

Comment: Okay, i used this query and now every duplicate number in column A is just 0 now and it is still visible

Comment: Made a small change based on OP's requirement hope you dont mind.

Comment: Okay, now the 0's are gone but there is just blank space now where the numbers used to be....how can I get rid of the blank space?

Comment: @Rataiczak24 - Empty string is converted to 0 because `A` is of integer type. `CASE` returns the highest precedence type from the set of types in result_expressions.

Comment: @Rataiczak24 - Actually what is your requirement? You mentioned *you want the "1" and "2" in column A displayed once*..That is what happening in above query. Can you update the question with expected result.

Comment: I am importing the values into a dropdown...so now there is a bunch of blank space in my dropdown

Comment: I updated my post to show you what part of my dropdown looks like...i think i may have been a bit unclear about not mentioning the dropdown

Comment: @Rataiczak24: well, do you actually want to remove all duplicates? Your screenshot shows only column A but not the other column. It's still unclear

Comment: no i do not want them removed...i just dont want to display them...i just want the dropdown to look cleaner so theres not all that blank space